# Why do I get Runtime Error when comparison function in std::sort always return true?

Tags: c++, sorting

Why do I get Runtime Error when comparison function in std::sort always return true?

```
bool compare(string a, string b)
{
    return true;
}

vector<string> Test;
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    Test.push_back(string("0"));
sort(Test.begin(), Test.end(), compare);
```

Comment: My guess is infinite recursion since your comparison operator is not deterministic.

Comment: @NathanOliver the operator is most certainly [deterministic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_algorithm).

Comment: @user2079303 Whats the fancy word for broken and wrong then?

Comment: @NathanOliver It doesn't do strict-weak ordering and therefore we get UB. Alternatively I guess you could say it leads to a non-deterministic sort because it depends on how many comparisons and the order of them and the implementation of the sort itself.

Comment: @Borgleader Thanks man.  That was what I was looking for.  For some reason I was drawing a blank.

Comment: I love that STL provides this test at runtime with debugbuild.

Comment: Visual Studio debug runtime would have stopped right away with an assertion.  The debug runtime checks if you're saying that a < b, and at the same time b < a by calling the compare function twice.  The first time  `compare(a, b)` is called, and right afterwards `compare(b, a)`. if they both return the same value (either both `true` or both `false`), you've violated the strict-weak-ordering criteria and the program stops.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The comparison function must meet the requirements of [Compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) concept. One of the requirements is:

> If comp(a,b)==true then comp(b,a)==false

Your function violates this requirement, so the program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: In the case of Visual Studio, a debug build will do this check (and force a runtime error), but I'm not sure if a release build does this check.

Answer (score 0):

You write qsort by taking an item at random, then separating all the input into "bigger" and "smaller" piles. Then you do the same to both of the piles. It only works if you more or less halve each pile on each step. If the comparison function always returns true, everything goes into the "bigger" pile, and thus the recursion never stops until the stack is exhausted and the computer reports an error.

That's probably what is happening.